# The \ Symbol usage in C# strings

Tags: c#

I have a line of code like this

```
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory =Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\bin";
```

but in the second string the "\" symbol isn't seen like a character of the string, how i can fix it?

The outputs of this line is "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Tesin"  where Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()= "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test"

Comment: Use `Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "bin")` to avoid these problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use @"\bin" or you need to escape any \ to \\ like "\\bin"

be aware using @"blahblahblah" changes the behave of escaping (a " must be escaped with "" instead of \" )

Answer (score 0):

write "\\bin" - the \ character needs to be escaped with \ so - \

Answer (score 0):

In many languages, the backslash (`\`) is an escape character, meaning it tells the system to take the *following* character *literal*.
You can just double the backslash, and it will work: `"\\bin"`